# Download BLOB PDF in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I'm trying to download a PDF file in a BLOB URL from my Webview app.
I've searched everywhere and I couldn't find a proper answer.

PS: I've tried this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954970/19611789 , and it did nothing